# 'df' hangs after a connection to a mounted smb (cifs) storage was lost

Tags: unix, mount, smb, cifs, umount

First I mount a storage from an SMB server using the command

```
sudo mount.cifs //{addr}/{path} /mnt/smb -o vers=2.0,guest
```

Second, I down a network interface (through which I have access to the SMB storage).

```
sudo ifconfig enp0s3 down
```

After that something goes wrong. For example the command

```
df
```

hangs for several minutes.

Is there's a way to mount a storage so that when the connection breaks only mountpoint becomes unavailable, not all the system?
I tried to read manual for mount.cifs but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: It *is* only the mounted filesystem that's unavailable.  The rest of the system is just fine. But `df` attempts to `statfs` all mounted filesystems, including this one.

Comment: I understand... But I'd like all my commands to work. I'd like this mountpoint unmounts.